# How to percentage two numbers and show final result in another td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of tr and tds and I show the percentage of sold ticket in third td. the problem of this code is it the result repeats wrong. i mean 2times of result is extra. and i think it happens because of my html format. but i can not change the format of my html code . what should i do ? here is my snippet :

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(7)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
    
  $('span.result', $this).html(
    $('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/).map(function(v, i) {
      return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0)+ '%';
    }).join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th>title </th>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-
</td>
<td>  
-
</td>
<td>
 -
</td>
<td>
10<br/>  
0<br/> 
</td>
<td>
5<br/>
0<br/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just remove one `<span class="result"></span><br/>` as when you are using `map` you are writing the 2 values already...

Comment: @balexandre i have 2 span called result but my result shows 4. if i remove br in my tds it work good but i can not remove them

Comment: if you can't remove, just output to one of them... change this `$('span.result', $this).html(...` into `$('span.result:first', $this).html(...` - so we add `:first` so you can only write text to the first one, not both... - **OR** you can simply remove one of them `$('span.result:last', $this).remove()` (for removing the last ...)

Comment: @balexandre i have to show each output separatly in each span

Comment: wouldn't be lovely you simply stated that in your question? would save so much effort!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the second `<span />` tag with class="result", but if you don't want to change your html you can use jQuery's `.first()` method to select only the first matching span.  To generalize such that each span's index dictates the index of the number in the other tds:

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(7)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);

  $('span.result', $this).each(function (index, element) {
    let v = $('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
    $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th>title </th>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-
</td>
<td>  
-
</td>
<td>
 -
</td>
<td>
10<br/>  
0<br/> 
</td>
<td>
5<br/>
0<br/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i have to show each output separatly in each span. is there any way to do somthing like this?

Comment: I believe what you want is something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXzQQL?editors=1111
Where for each span you want the corresponding line in the 6th and 7th `td` ?

Comment: yes somthing like this. nut in this code i can not see the result ?actually i want too keep the spans and put each result of 6th an 7th on them.

Comment: I've updated the code above, you can run it to see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @aynaz - I don't know why you were looking for this code.
The line  let v = $('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/); will be executed for each span. But in my code it will be only once.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(7)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
    
  $('span.result', $this).html(
    $('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/).map(function(v, i) {
      return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0)+ '%';
    }).join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th> title </th>
                  <th>  title </th>
                  <th>title </th>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-</td>
<td>
-
</td>
<td>  
-
</td>
<td>
 -
</td>
<td>
10<br/>  
0<br/> 
</td>
<td>
5<br/>
0<br/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i can not change the html format. spans should be 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are rigid in your HTML, then we have a solution.
Change your JavaScript code slightly:

```
$('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/).forEach(function(v, i) {
    $('span.result', $this)[i].innerHTML = Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0) + '%';
});
```

Comment: so where should i define  td:nth-child(7) ?

Comment: It will be same as you defined.
You have to just replace this code:

 $('span.result', $this).html(
    $('td:nth-child(6)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/).map(function(v, i) {
      return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0)+ '%';
    }).join('<br>'));